# What is the correct expression to generate the correct result?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

This script takes a CSV file and iterates over it to create a MD array.  It then takes the third column and compares each variable to determine if it is greater than 64.  I can get it to work if I use the number 64, but it will not work when using a declared constant named MAX_AGE.

Below is an image of the script using -gt MAX_AGE
[image: script with declared constant MAX_AGE]

Below is the error using the above script
[image]

I know the answer is probably something simple.......

Comment: Do not put _images_ of code into questions: you should not expect people to read the image and retype your code in order to test it.  Copy-and paste the actual code into the question.  Then use the `{}` button to format it as a code.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

`-gt` is used for comparing numbers, not strings.  Thus, you need to replace:

```
[ ${ages[i]} -gt MAX_AGE ]
```

with:

```
[ ${ages[i]} -gt $MAX_AGE ]
```

The reason for this is that `MAX_AGE` is a string.  You cannot use it as a number.

`$MAX_AGE` is the value of the variable `MAX_AGE`.  You can compare that to a number as long as that value can be interpreted as an integer.

For best results when using `[...]`, variables should be double-quoted:

```
[ "${ages[i]}" -gt "$MAX_AGE" ]
```